# Integral of characteristic and density function

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

Let X and Y be random variables (real valued) with density functions $f_X, f_Y$  and characteristic functions $I_X, I_Y$.
How can we show that:
$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{I_X(y) f_Y(y) e^{-ity}dy} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{I_Y{(x-t)f_X(x)}dx}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Write out $I_X(y)$ in terms of an integral using that $X$ has density $f_X$. Then apply Fubini's theorem.

---

**Edit**:
The characeristic function $I_X$ can be written as
$$
I_X(t)={\rm E}\left[e^{itX}\right]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{itx}f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx
$$
and plugging this into the left-hand side, we get
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty I_X(y)f_Y(y)e^{-ity}\mathrm dy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{iyx}f_X(x)e^{-ity}f_Y(y) \,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy.
$$

Now apply (the complex version of) Fubini's theorem.

Comment: Ok, so we have: $ ... = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{exp(iyx) f_X(x) dx} + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{f_Y(y) e^{-ity}dy} $ on the left side. I hope this is correct. We now could write: $exp(iyx) = cos(yx) + isin(yx) $, but I don't know if this is useful... Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: @JohnD: I gave you a start. Now try to see if you can arrive at the right-hand side.

Comment: Thanks for your start and your hints! I have still 1 Problem: I don't get it how to achieve $ I_Y(x-t) $ , especially this (x-t) :S

Comment: @JohnD: I fixed a typo. Should be straightforward now.